# Take a picture while camera preview on Android using Camera2

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am trying to use "camera preview" and "face detection" using Camera2 and MLKIT face-detection , the preview and face detection works fine , but i cannot take a picture while showing the preview.

LivePreviewActivity :

```
public final class LivePreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, OnItemSelectedListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
private static final String FACE_DETECTION = "Face Detection";

private static final String TAG = "LivePreviewActivity";
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUESTS = 1;

private CameraSource cameraSource = null;
private CameraSourcePreview preview;
private GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
private String selectedModel = FACE_DETECTION;
private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Button takePic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vision_live_preview);

    preview = findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    if (preview == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preview is null");
    }
    graphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay);
    if (graphicOverlay == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "graphicOverlay is null");
    }

    ToggleButton facingSwitch = findViewById(R.id.facing_switch);
    facingSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    takePic = findViewById(R.id.take_pic);

    ImageView settingsButton = findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_LAUNCH_SOURCE, SettingsActivity.LaunchSource.LIVE_PREVIEW);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        createCameraSource(selectedModel);
    } else {
        getRuntimePermissions();
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    selectedModel = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "Selected model: " + selectedModel);
    preview.stop();
    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        createCameraSource(selectedModel);
        startCameraSource();
    } else {
        getRuntimePermissions();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Set facing");
    if (cameraSource != null) {
        if (isChecked) {
            cameraSource.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        } else {
            cameraSource.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        }
    }
    preview.stop();
    startCameraSource();
}

private void createCameraSource(String model) {
    // If there's no existing cameraSource, create one.
    if (cameraSource == null) {
        cameraSource = new CameraSource(this, graphicOverlay);
    }

    try {
        switch (model) {
            case FACE_DETECTION:
                Log.i(TAG, "Using Face Detector Processor");
                FaceDetectorOptions faceDetectorOptions = PreferenceUtils.getFaceDetectorOptionsForLivePreview(this);
                cameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(new FaceDetectorProcessor(this, faceDetectorOptions));
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown model: " + model);
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not create image processor: " + model, e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can not create image processor: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists. If the camera source doesn't exist yet
 * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
 * again when the camera source is created.
 */
private void startCameraSource() {
    if (cameraSource != null) {
        try {
            if (preview == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "resume: Preview is null");
            }
            if (graphicOverlay == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "resume: graphOverlay is null");
            }

            preview.start(cameraSource, graphicOverlay);

           
            final ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
            cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                        bindPreview(cameraProvider);

                    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                        // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                        // This should never be reached.
                    }
                }
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
            cameraSource.release();
            cameraSource = null;
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
            cameraSource.release();
            cameraSource = null;
        }
    }
}
void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
    cameraProvider.unbindAll();
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
    final ImageCapture imageCapture = builder.setTargetRotation(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(String.valueOf(cameraSource.getCameraFacing()).equals("0")?1:0).build();

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder().build();
    MyAnalyzer myAnalyzer = new MyAnalyzer();
    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, myAnalyzer);

    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis, imageCapture);

    takePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
            File file = new File(getBatchDirectoryName(), mDateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".jpg");

            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
            imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(LivePreviewActivity.this, "Image Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    createCameraSource(selectedModel);
    startCameraSource();
}

/**
 * Stops the camera.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    preview.stop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (cameraSource != null) {
        cameraSource.release();
    }
}

private String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        String[] ps = info.requestedPermissions;
        if (ps != null && ps.length > 0) {
            return ps;
        } else {
            return new String[0];
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String[0];
    }
}

private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
    for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
        if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void getRuntimePermissions() {
    List<String> allNeededPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
        if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
            allNeededPermissions.add(permission);
        }
    }

    if (!allNeededPermissions.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, allNeededPermissions.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUESTS);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted!");
    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        createCameraSource(selectedModel);
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

private static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, String permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted: " + permission);
        return true;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Permission NOT granted: " + permission);
    return false;
}

public String getBatchDirectoryName() {
    String app_folder_path = "";
    app_folder_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images";
    File dir = new File(app_folder_path);
    if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
    }
    return app_folder_path;
}

private class MyAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    @androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
    public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {
        Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            InputImage image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
            // Pass image to an ML Kit Vision API
            // ...
        }
    }
}
}
```

CameraSourcePreview :

```
  public class CameraSourcePreview extends ViewGroup {
                      private static final String TAG = "MIDemoApp:Preview";

                      private final Context context;
                      private final SurfaceView surfaceView;
                      private boolean startRequested;
                      private boolean surfaceAvailable;
                      private CameraSource cameraSource;

                      private GraphicOverlay overlay;

                      public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                        super(context, attrs);
                        this.context = context;
                        startRequested = false;
                        surfaceAvailable = false;

                        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
                        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
                        addView(surfaceView);
                      }

                      private void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException {
                        this.cameraSource = cameraSource;

                        if (this.cameraSource != null) {
                          startRequested = true;
                          startIfReady();
                        }
                      }

                      public void start(CameraSource cameraSource, GraphicOverlay overlay) throws IOException {
                        this.overlay = overlay;
                        start(cameraSource);
                      }


                      public void stop() {
                        if (cameraSource != null) {
                          cameraSource.stop();
                        }
                      }

                      public void release() {
                        if (cameraSource != null) {
                          cameraSource.release();
                          cameraSource = null;
                        }
                        surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface().release();
                      }

                      private void startIfReady() throws IOException, SecurityException {
                        if (startRequested && surfaceAvailable) {
                          if (PreferenceUtils.isCameraLiveViewportEnabled(context)) {
                            cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                          } else {
                            cameraSource.start();
                          }
                          requestLayout();

                          if (overlay != null) {
                            Size size = cameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                            int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                            int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                            boolean isImageFlipped = cameraSource.getCameraFacing() == CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                            if (isPortraitMode()) {
                              // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by 90 degrees.
                              // The camera preview and the image being processed have the same size.
                              overlay.setImageSourceInfo(min, max, isImageFlipped);
                            } else {
                              overlay.setImageSourceInfo(max, min, isImageFlipped);
                            }
                            overlay.clear();
                          }
                          startRequested = false;
                        }
                      }

                      private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
                        @Override
                        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surface) {
                          surfaceAvailable = true;
                          try {
                            startIfReady();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
                          }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surface) {
                          surfaceAvailable = false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
                        int width = 320;
                        int height = 240;
                        if (cameraSource != null) {
                          Size size = cameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                          if (size != null) {
                            width = size.getWidth();
                            height = size.getHeight();
                          }
                        }

                        // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
                        if (isPortraitMode()) {
                          int tmp = width;
                          width = height;
                          height = tmp;
                        }

                        float previewAspectRatio = (float) width / height;
                        int layoutWidth = right - left;
                        int layoutHeight = bottom - top;
                        float layoutAspectRatio = (float) layoutWidth / layoutHeight;
                        if (previewAspectRatio > layoutAspectRatio) {
                          // The preview input is wider than the layout area. Fit the layout height and crop
                          // the preview input horizontally while keep the center.
                          int horizontalOffset = (int) (previewAspectRatio * layoutHeight - layoutWidth) / 2;
                          surfaceView.layout(-horizontalOffset, 0, layoutWidth + horizontalOffset, layoutHeight);
                        } else {
                          // The preview input is taller than the layout area. Fit the layout width and crop the preview
                          // input vertically while keep the center.
                          int verticalOffset = (int) (layoutWidth / previewAspectRatio - layoutHeight) / 2;
                          surfaceView.layout(0, -verticalOffset, layoutWidth, layoutHeight + verticalOffset);
                        }
                      }

                      private boolean isPortraitMode() {
                        int orientation = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                          return false;
                        }
                        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                          return true;
                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
                        return false;
                      }
                    }
```

when i click on the button to take the picture nothing happened , ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() is never called , what can be wrong and how can i achieve it.

Comment: It should be straightforward with CameraX. Is there a reason you don't want to use CameraX?

Comment: the code i am using is working fine (face detection with graphics overlay) , with CameraX the overlay is not fit over face , so i have to use the Camera2 api

Comment: For camera2 implementation,  you can check out the camera2 code sample: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic. However just FYI, it's very difficult to make your app compatible across all devices with camera2. That's why Google introduced CameraX.